# Data structure for storing list of boolean values mapped to string names in vb

Tags: data-structures

What would be a good (in terms of speed, code safety etc.) data structure for storing boolean values mapped to a list of string names vb? The strings are a list of length 22 with distinct names like "A201" "A202" etc.

```
<string, True> 
<string, False> 
<string, True> 
<string, False>
```

I then need to loop through this list. Speed is essential as each iteration needs to be as quick as possible.

I was thinking, alternative to using a data structure, I could place the 22 strings inside an array and then set them to nothing, and loop through them to see which ones are not set to nothing, then process based only on the strings that are not set to nothing. I was just wondering whether a particular data structure would be a better solution and how the solutions would compare?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have a list of 22 strings that you need to loop through? I don't think you need to be very concerned about speed for such a small list.

Comment: Hi, the issue is that for each of the list string key, I need to perform a rather long set of functions if the boolean value is true. In addition, the list needs to be re-looped once every few minutes.

Comment: You may want to focus your efforts on speeding up the "long set of functions" you're referring to. There also isn't really enough information here to give you a useful answer — for example, how often does this list of 22 strings change? Do the strings ever change or just the booleans?

Comment: How many true, how many false ?

Comment: @Shim: The strings do not change, but the boolean values in the list changes every single iteration, but each iteration may have a different number of changes. Unless we are using an array, in which case the list of strings would have a variable number of strings set to nothing each iteration.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: The list is set to 22 False values initially.

Comment: Couldn't you maintain two separate lists, one of strings you want to do more work on and one of strings you don't, and move the strings between the lists when needed? Then you don't need to iterate through the full list every time or check booleans each time. Although moving strings between lists might be expensive, depending on the implementation. You could try a few different methods with 100 iterations or something, and compare the execution times to figure out what is fastest.

Comment: @Shim: the thing is that I am running a process in which I can only add ones which I don't need to do more work on to an additional list. This means I would still have to two for loops, matching the new list to identify which of the original list still needs to do work.

Comment: @Shim: thanks! I think I could remove the string from the original list for the ones that don't need any more work, then pass the updated list (containing the ones that need more work) to the re-loop when the first loop through the list is completed.

Comment: If you've solved your problem you can post an answer here — I would do it but I think you have a better idea of the solution than I do.

Comment: @Shim: thanks for the help, I have posted answer as below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could remove the string from the original list for the ones that don't need any more work, then pass the updated list (containing the ones that need more work) to the re-loop when the first loop through the list is completed.